# Monodroid EditText input type number detect enter keypress

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-edittext, event-handling, numbers

I'm trying to make a tablet application that has several edittext fields that are set to InputType="number" so it looks like a small keypad rather than an entire keyboard.  This is obviously because I only want numbers entered into the field.

However, I'd like to detect IF the user hits the ENTER key.  If they do, I'd like to close the Soft Keyboard -- so it's easy and more accessible than hitting that little down-arrow button to hide the keyboard.  I've already done this exact thing for another edittext box on the screen that accepts all characters (using the default keyboard) and that works fine.  But for some reason when I attempt to detect the keypress from the Numeric Keypad I am unable to do so.

So here's the problem that I can't seem to figure out: when I add a listener to the keypad, NOTHING works.  No numbers seem to appear on the screen.  If I remove the listener, the numpad works fine again but then I can't listen for the enter key being pressed so i can close the soft keyboard.

So, here's what I got:

```
          <EditText
          android:id="@+id/NumOfAdults_EditText"
          android:layout_width="70sp"
          android:layout_height="50sp"
          android:inputType="number"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            />
```

And I listen for it like this:

```
          var editTextBox = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.NumOfAdults_EditText);
          editTextBox.KeyPress += (intentSender, e) =>
          {
            if (e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down && e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter)
            {
                CloseSoftKeyboard();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
          };
```

So does anyone have any idea why when I do this, the number input keys STOP working?  This code totally works fine when the inputType isn't set to number or phone.  What's funny is if I add a Make.Toast inside the detection, I can actually see the keypresses working (and can even get Num0-9 to show) but again nothing seems to work on screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the **DispatchKeyEvent** method of your activity and put in some code like this. It is going to get called for all button presses though, so try to make it as restrictive as possible.

In this example replace *etTheIdOfYourEditTextControl* with the actual name of the field(s) that you would like this behavior to occur on.

```
public override bool DispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (this.CurrentFocus.Id == Resource.Id.etTheIdOfYourEditTextControl && (e.KeyCode == Keycode.NumpadEnter || e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter))
        {
            InputMethodManager imm = GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
            if (imm != null)
                imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.CurrentFocus.WindowToken, 0);

            return true;
        }

        return base.DispatchKeyEvent(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time, but still show the solution:

```
if (...) // Handle some key
{
    ...
}
else if (...) // Handle another key
{
    ...
}
else
{
    e.Handled = false; // if you want that character appeared on the screen
}
```